# Writing in database via JSON php issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

Here is the code is written is RadarsMySql.php

```
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","dacian");


 $db = mysql_select_db("radars");

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT latitude,longitude,description FROM radars WHERE id > '0'");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
 $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 foreach($out["radars"] as $radars) { 
 $latitude = addslashes($radars[latitude]); 
 $longitude= addslashes($radars[longitude]); 
 $description = addslashes($radars[description]);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO radars (latitude, longitude, description) VALUES('$name', '$ingredients', '$ingredients2')") or die (mysql_error()); 
 }

  mysql_close(); ?>
```

It gives me this error :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: out in C:\xampp\htdocs\RadarsMySql.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\RadarsMySql.php on line 13
```

I need this because i want to write data from android app using JSON. Could anyone tell me what is wrong or to give me some tips ?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `$output` instead of `$out` ?

Comment: The error messages PHP gives you are helpful, clear, and informative. Did you try reading them?

Comment: From what I see, $out is not defined as an array anywhere. What should $out be?

Comment: Care with **SQL injections**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($out["radars"] as $radars) {}
```

If `$out["radars"]` is an array, this is fine. If it isn't, you'll get a bug: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach`.

In your case `$out["radars"]` doesn't exist at all. In fact `$out` doesn't exist at all. So you get another bug: `Undefined variable out`.

You're initialising a variable `$output` but then trying to use it as `$out`. That won't work.

To pull data out of the database, encode it as JSON, and output it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT latitude,longitude,description FROM radars WHERE id>0'
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $rows[] = $row;
echo json_encode($rows);
```

And to receive JSON posted to the server, process it, and add it to the database:

```
// It's being posted as application/json, not as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so it won't populate the $_POST array.
if ($json = file_get_contents('php://input')) {
    // Never mind. We'll do it ourselves.
    $a = json_decode($json, true); // Now we have a nice PHP array.
    $insert = '';
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        if ($insert) $insert .= ',';
        $insert .= ' ("' . $d->escape($v['lattitude']) . '", "' . $d->escape($v['longitude']) . '", "' . $d->escape($v['description']) . '")';
    }
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `radars` (`latitude`, `longitude`, `description`) VALUES' . $insert;
    $d->exec($sql);
}

// I'm assuming you have a database class here, $d.
// $d->exec() could be simply mysql_query() or mysqli_query().
// $d->escape() should be mysql_real_escape_string() or mysqli_real_escape_string(), but both of those functions will fail if a database connection is not currently open.
// So $d->escape() should (a) check whether a connection is currently open, (b) open one if not, (c) perform the escape and return the result.
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: radars in C:\xampp\htdocs\RadarsMySql.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\RadarsMySql.php on line 13

Comment: that's what i get after i modified out with ouput. It's ok ?

Comment: @stanga. I don't know what `$output` is. Try `print_r($output); exit;` and add that to the question.

Comment: Actually, scrap that. I'm going to completely rewrite my answer.

Comment: Ok. I don't really understand what you say but I wonder if you know a tutorial or you could say me what should I do / write there the enstablish a connection between android application and mysql database ?

Comment: @stanga. See rewrite. I see you've already marked my answer as correct, even before the rewrite. I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: You understood wrong. I know how to pull data, I don't know how to write data ... THAT IS MY PROBLEM !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11163/discussion-between-trig-and-stanga-bogdan)

Comment: Oh. The automatic comment it puts in when I move to chat is phrased really poncy.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining $out? ;)

```
foreach($out["radars"] as $radars) {
```

Comment: ... nowhere. I'm a newbie in mysql/php programming. Could you help me with this ? I have 3 columns latitude , longitude , description . How could i write the php to allow me posting from android app ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     foreach($output["radars"] as $radars) {
```

which you have created above print statement

Comment: it's ok if I only receive a notice and a warning ? no errors ?